# Radio button show both result check and uncheck

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

There are many profiles in the DB, I'm fetching those Data using PHP.
I want to make a single profile default from too many profiles.
For making profile default I'm using a radio button.
code below

```
$("input:radio[name=selection]").click(function() {
   if($(this).is(':checked')) {

       $(".loader-overley").show(); //show loading image
            $.ajax({
            url: "addDefault_update.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                col_profile_id: $(this).attr('id'),      
            },
            success: function (data) {
            $(".loader-overley").hide(); //hide loading image
                alert('Item Updated Successfully !');
                window.location.href = 'viewCoProfile';

            }
        });

         }else{ }
});
```

IF condition is working correctly.

**My concern is**
when I checked radio button at the same unchecked event should fire

Comment: Why do you want to uncheck ?

Comment: then instead of binding from click, bind `onchange`

Comment: why the php tag? if there is no relevance, it should be removed or add the relevant code for it.

Comment: @Ashvin777 is checked is inserting data into DB and for unchecking I want to remove some flag from db which i have set

Comment: there's also no HTML or db-related stuff. Seeing the answer below didn't solve this, then the question is unclear. Note: As I am typing this out, it seems they have deleted their answer. Edit: and now it's been undeleted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- , added again, but definitely it not clear what OP want to do

Comment: @JigarShah I noticed and edited my above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add code into `else` part.

`$(this).is(':checked')` returns `true` or `false`. You have written code for `true` , now add appropriate code for `false`.

Comment: both checked and unchecked flag should run at the same time
checked for inserting data and unchecked for removing data. I'm stuck at unchecked

Comment: checked and unchecked can not work together. You need to re-think for your logical part .

Comment: Thank you i did at server side

Comment: Welcome, you can accept as answer if found helpful enough and close this qustion